# Iinsert Start and enddate and when the dates are overlaping it change the Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following database structure with example:
[Testing T-SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGWUC.png)

My goal is that when I'm inserting a new row like this for example:

`INSERT INTO EventTesting (StartDate, EndDate) VALUES ('2023-01-08', '2023-01-15');`

then the code should avoid overlaping so it looks like that in the end:

[EndOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU8Z9.png)

What I want is to create an Trigger which is activating before the insert is happening. What I have tried is to use this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PreventOverlap
ON EventTesting
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NewStartDate DATE, @NewEndDate DATE

    SELECT @NewStartDate = StartDate, @NewEndDate = EndDate
    FROM inserted

    UPDATE EventTesting
    SET EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @NewStartDate)
    WHERE ID IN (
        SELECT ID
        FROM EventTesting
        WHERE ID <> (SELECT ID FROM inserted)
        AND StartDate < @NewStartDate
        AND EndDate >= @NewStartDate
    )

    INSERT INTO EventTesting (StartDate, EndDate)
    VALUES (@NewStartDate, @NewEndDate)
END
```

But what I got is now this output:

[wrong output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5KSh.png)

What am I missing or should change so I have the desired output?

Comment: Recommended reading: [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers) & [The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/) A DML statement can affect 0+ rows, not *only* 1.

Comment: Also, T-SQL is a SQL dialect that is used by multiple products including Sybase, SQL Server, and Azure Synapse. What is the (R)DBMS product you are using here? [Edit] your question to tag that product, and (if relevant) the version tag for the product as well.

Comment: Not to mention: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: How do you want to handle a single `insert` statement that adds multiple rows and where the inserted rows contain overlaps?

Comment: @ThomA - if `t-sql` by itself isn't valid, what use is it as a tag at all?

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't helpful, *however*, on it's own it doesn't tell us what we can use. The 3 products I list, for example, have different "levels" of support for features in the dialect; letting us know what we can use is important. Much like [[tag:sql-server]], on it's own, doesn't tell us what version the OP is using (and some people are (very) foolishly still using versions like 2005 & 2008...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use instead of insert trigger and merge command for insert or update operation when it necessary.
Here is new trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER PreventOverlap
        ON EventTesting
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  set nocount on;
  with newInserts (sd, ed) as
      (
        select StartDate, lead(StartDate ) over (order by StartDate)
        from (
          select StartDate from EventTesting
          union 
          select EndDate from EventTesting
          union
          select StartDate from inserted
          union
          select EndDate from inserted
        ) aa
     )
        merge EventTesting as trg
        using ( select sd, ed from newInserts where ed is not null) as src (StartDate, EndDate) on 
          trg.StartDate = src.StartDate 
          when not matched     
          then insert (StartDate, EndDate) values (src.StartDate, src.EndDate)
          when matched and trg.EndDate <> src.EndDate
          then update set EndDate=src.EndDate
          ;
    end
```